# Referencing a reference returned by std::optional::operator*()

Tags: c++, option-type

I was reading some code today when I discovered curiously that it appears to be legal to reference a reference returned by `std::optional`.

So I started producing a minimal example but ran into a few oddities. I have 3 questions that perhaps someone can explain for me.

1. Why does `funcA(&*opta1)` not compile?
2. Why does the constructor for `opta3` not compile? It seems the only difference to `optb3` is an empty parameter-pack?
3. Is it actually legal to reference a reference?

```
#include <experimental/optional>

using namespace ::std::experimental;

struct A {
  int num_ = 1;
};

// Same as struct A but with non-default constructor
struct B {
  int num_;
  B(int num) : num_(num) {}
};


void funcA(A * a) {}

void funcB(B * b) {}

int main() {
  optional<A> opta1(A());
  optional<A> opta2 = make_optional<A>(A());
  // optional<A> opta3 = make_optional<A>(); // Why doesn't this compile?

  // funcA(&*opta1); // Why doesn't this compile?
  funcA(&*opta2);
  // funcA(&*opta3); 

  optional<B> optb1(B(1));
  optional<B> optb2 = make_optional<B>(B(1));
  optional<B> optb3 = make_optional<B>(1); // Compiles now? Only difference is non-empty parameter pack?

  funcB(&*optb1); // But this compiles?
  funcB(&*optb2);
  funcB(&*optb3);
}
```

Compiler Explorer so you can manipulate it easier:
https://godbolt.org/g/oFLcS1

Comment: At first glance, read up on C++'s most vexing parse. You have a function, not a variable. Generally, use curly braces `{}` for constructor argument list, unless you really need the `()` constructor variant (e.g. for `std::string`).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf:

I had not caught the most vexing parse. That totally answers question 1. Thanks

However, if you know why, I'd appreciate pointers for answers to question 2 and 3 which don't appear to be related to most vexing parse?

Comment: Found the answer to my own question 3:

Taking the address of a reference is taking the address of the referent:
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#reseating-refs

So that just leaves question 2.